# regression with indepdent variables that I know the relative weight of

Tags: weighted-regression

I want to do a regression of a continuous dependent variable (y) (say number of crystals formed) using several independent variables (also continuous), each represent the temperature of each of the plates that are encountered in the crystal-making process (this is a made-up scenario to illustrate the problem I'm having) (say 4, lets call them x1, x2, x3, x4), the thing is, I know the relative "weight" of each IV (time spent on each plate). For example, it takes 100 minutes to form crystals, and this 100 minutes are spent staying on 4 different plates with different temperature. the amount of time spent on each plate is different, say (20, 30, 10, 20, 20). so in this case, the raw materials for the crystal stay on plate 1 (x1) for 20 %of the total time, and stay on plate 2 (x2) for 30 % of the total time. and the amount of time on each plate stays the same WITHIN each batch. but the amount of time on each plate is different BETWEEN batches.

I have 10 batches. my question is, how do I do the regression of y (number of crystal formed) against the IV (x1-x4, the temperatures of each of the 4 plates used to make the crystal), taking into account of the time the raw materials stay on each plate, when I do separate regression for each batch individually (the amount of time spent on each plates stays constant)? and when I do one regression for all of the batches together (so there are different amounts of time for each plate for each batch)?

many thanks!

Comment: Number of crystals is not a continuous variable. It's a count. (Although it might not matter if the count is high and has a lot of variability).